# Java ListStack<A> push and pushAll() method

Tags: java, list, stack, push, postfix-notation

We have a Liststack and an ADTStackJqwikTest.
Here's my code in ListStack for the push and the pushAll() method.

```
   @Override
    public Stack<A> push(A e) {
        return new ListStack(list.cons(e));
    }
```

```
@Override
    public Stack<A> pushAll(List<A> xs) {
        return xs.isEmpty() ? this : new ListStack<A>(List.append(xs, list));
    }
```

In my ListStack I've a test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stack<Integer> s1 = empty();
        s1 = s1.pushAll(list(1,2,3));
        s1 = s1.pushAll(list(1,2,3));
        System.out.println("PushAll: " + s1.toList());

        Stack<Integer> s2 = empty();
        s2 = s2.push(1);
        s2 = s2.push(2);
        s2 = s2.push(3);
        s2 = s2.push(1);
        s2 = s2.push(2);
        s2 = s2.push(3);
        System.out.println("Push:    " + s2.toList());
    }
}
```

the result I get is:
PushAll: 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3
Push:    3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1

But the result should be the same. What do I wrong?

In my ADTStackJqwikTest I've to pushAll() methods.

```
// ∀s:Stack<A> : pushAll([],s) = s
    @Property
    <A> boolean pushAll(@ForAll("stacks") Stack<A> s) {
        return s.pushAll(List.list()).equals(s);
    }

    // ∀s:Stack<A>, ∀xs:List<A> : pushAll(x:xs,s)= push(x,pushAll(xs,s)), falls s nicht leer
    @Property
    <A> boolean pushAll(@ForAll("stacks") Stack<A> s, @ForAll("lists") List<A> xs, @ForAll("as") A x) {
        return s.pushAll(xs.cons(x)).equals(s.push(x).pushAll(xs));
    }
```

Comment: Where does the lowercased `list` come from?

Comment: From the class: public class ListStack<A> implements Stack<A> {

    private final List<A> list;

    private ListStack(List<A> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    private ListStack() {
        this.list = list();
    }

Comment: Let's see the code for "list.cons(e)".

Comment: public List<A> cons(A a) {
            return new Cons<>(a, this);
        }

Comment: Note: cons("a", list("b","c")) = (a b c) , so push 1,2,3  => 3,2,1 in the list?

Answer (score 1):

```
package stack;
```

import list.List;
import tuple.Tuple;

import static list.List.list;

public class ListStack implements Stack {

```
private final List<A> list;

private ListStack(List<A> list) {
    this.list = list;
}

private ListStack() {
    this.list = list();
}

@Override
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return list.isEmpty();
}

@Override
public Stack<A> push(A e) {
    return new ListStack<A>(list.cons(e));
}

@Override
public Stack<A> pop() {
    if(isEmpty())
        throw new IllegalStateException("pop from an empty stack");
    else return new ListStack<A>(list.tail());
}

@Override
public A top() {
    if(isEmpty())
        throw new IllegalStateException("top from an empty stack");
     else return list.head();
}

@Override
public Tuple<A, Stack<A>> popTop() {
    return Tuple.tuple(top(), pop());
}

@Override
public Tuple<List<A>, Stack<A>> popTopAll() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public Stack<A> pushAll(List<A> xs) {
    return xs.isEmpty() ? this : new ListStack<A>(List.append(xs, list));
}

@Override
public List<A> toList() {
    return list;
}

@Override
public boolean isEqualTo(Stack<A> s) {
    return this.toList().isEqualTo(s.toList());
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    return o instanceof Stack && isEqualTo((Stack) o);
}

public String toString() {
    return list.toString();
}

public static <A> Stack<A> empty() {
    return new ListStack(list());
}
```

This is my whole ListStack

Comment: can you share also the implementation of List.cons?

Answer (score 0):

change

```
@Override
public Stack<A> pushAll(List<A> xs) {
    return xs.isEmpty() ? this : new ListStack<A>(List.append(xs, list));
}
```

into

```
@Override
public Stack<A> pushAll(List<A> xs) {
    return xs.isEmpty() ? this : new ListStack<A>(List.append(list, xs));
}
```

Comment: Same result. Doesn't change anything for the result.

Answer (score -1):

Okay I got it. Thank you guys.
The mistake was the append in the pushAll method.

Comment: A reply has to be a comment or an accepted answer or an upvote. But it should not be an answer.